# Why sound is not playing until click or touch on android device

Tags: android, ionic-framework

Why sound is not playing until click or touch on mobile app:

```
handleMessage(message){
    // condition check
    const audio = new Audio(Utils.getSoundAudio());
    audio.autoplay = false;
    audio.play()
}

socket.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
    handleMessage(event.data);
});
```

As per this documentation it is behaving very similarly: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/

How to solve this problem?